# Add attribute to wiredep or gulp-inject css link?

Tags: node.js, gulp, wiredep, gulp-inject

How can I add a custom html attribute to one css file using either wiredep or gulp-inject?  Every single other file is injected automatically, using Gulp, except for this one file (because I need to add an attribute to it):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title page-title></title>

<!-- build:css styles/lib.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:css styles/app.css -->
<!-- inject:css -->
<!-- endinject -->
<link id="loadBefore" href="/theme/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: which file, which attribute??? is the one with the id? give some context please.

Comment: @rick: notice the `id` attribute on the only `<link>` tag.  That was manually added.  I would like some way to load the `.css` files but automagically notate certain files with attributes they may need... like the `id="loadBefore"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use the transform option in the inject command in your gulp file

```
var addIdToCss = function (filepath, file, i, length) {
    return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filepath + '" id="YourId">';
}

inject(yourFile, {transform: addIdToCss, ...})
```